# Kolmogorov 0-1 law for convergence/divergence in a series of iid random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, independence

I've been dealing with this problem for some time and I haven't gotten a proper solution. This is it:

> Suppose that $\{ X_{n}: n \geq 1 \}$ are independent (not necessarily identically distributed) with $E[X_{n}]=0$ and $P(X_{n}=0)<1$. Let $S_{n}=X_{1}+\dots+X_{n}$. Show that either
>
> $$
> P\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_{n} \text{ exists} \right) = 1 \text{ or } P\left( \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_{n} = -\infty \text{ and } \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_{n} = \infty \right) = 1.
> $$
>
> **Hint:** Use Kolmogorov’s zero-one law and use the fact that $S_{n}$ is a martingale.

---

To start, I'm considering the sequence of events $A_{i} = \{X_{i} \not = 0 \}$, which are independent since the $X_{n}$ are independent. Thus any event int the tail $\sigma$-field
$$
\tau = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma(A_{n},A_{n+1},\dots)
$$
has probability 0 or 1 by the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

If we consider the event where $S_{n}$ converges, this is an event in the tail $\sigma$-field. By Kolmogorov 0-1 law we have then

$$
P(S_{n} \text{ converges}) = 1 \text{ or } P(S_{n} \text{ converges}) = 0.
$$

If the former happens then necessarily

$$
P\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_{n} \text{ exists} \right) = 1
$$

so we have the first part. If the later happens then the series diverges with probability 1 but I'm not sure how to conclude that

$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_{n} = -\infty \text{ and } \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_{n} = \infty
$$

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, thinking out loud. Only 3 things are possible -- convergence, divergence to $\pm \infty$ and oscillation. To model this last part, if $X_i$ are iid uniform over $\{-1,1\}$, they have zero expectation, but the sum should not converge. I wonder if lim sup or lim inf can be bounded, but don't think so -- they may be smth like $\ln n$ or $\ln \ln n$, but still converge to $\pm \infty$ as $n \to \infty$...